# How do I implement ToTraversable in Shapeless?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have `DL <: HList` and am trying to use `mkString` on `detailsIn: DL`:

```
val detail: String = detailsIn.mkString("", "; ", "")
```

`mkString` is defined as the following in Shapeless:

```
  def mkString(start: String, sep: String, end: String)
    (implicit toTraversable: ToTraversable.Aux[L, List, Any]): String = this.toList.mkString(start, sep, end)
```

I've seen a number of examples defining a function that requires a ToTraversable implict, but have yet to see anyone actually create a value of it (I suspect I'm not well versed enough in Shapeless to find these things as easily as I should be able to).

I have the following fragment that I needs to have the `???` filled in, and if that is correct, I think an example would be immensely helpful:

```
implicit val dlToList: ToList[DL, Any] = new ToTraversable[DL, List] {???}
```

However, I suspect there might be factory method to do this already, but if so I haven't found it.

Answer (score 3):

You are not expected to instantiate this value yourself. Instead, you should ask for it as an additional implicit parameter and let the compiler  do the work:

```
def myMethod[DL <: HList](detailsIn: DL)(implicit ev: ToTraversable.Aux[DL, List, Any]) = {
  val detail: String = detailsIn.mkString("", "; ", "")
  println(detail)
}
```

**Edit**:

1. Don't use IntelliJ
2. > If myMethod can find the implicit, why can't mkString find it?

   Because from the point of view a `myMethod`, you are looking for `ToTraversable[DL, List]` for any `DL <: HList`! The compiler cannot possibly figure out that for every possible instance of `DL`, it's possible to derive a `ToTraversable` (even if in this particular case, that might be probable by structural induction).

   In contrast, the place where actually do the call `myMethod(1 :: "s" :: HNil)` should have all the static information to implicitly resolve `ToTraversable.Aux[Int :: String :: HNil, List, Any]`. But you might ask, what if I wan't to call `myMethod` also in a generic context? You then have no choice but to propagate that implicit constraint further up the call chain, all the way until all genericity is gone.

Comment: If myMethod can find the implicit, why can't mkString find it?

Comment: I expect one reason is that it isn't in scope, but why? Is it a design decision to allow more flexibility in choosing the implicit?

Comment: I tried compiling your example but it still failed for me in this project MWE: https://github.com/bbarker/ProjectGists/tree/master/Scala/ShapelessToTraversable ; perhaps I'm missing an appropriate include. IntelliJ doesn't catch the issue, but I suppose that isn't surprising.